# Как в CActiveForm добавить переменную для отправки полученную из Javascript функции.

Tags: json, yii

Добрый день всем.

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь совместить плагин jQuery EasyUi с Yii, есть список чекбоксов, но они сделаны по хитрому и не есть на самом деле чекбоксами, а на самом деле обычные span.

Функция которая получает отмеченные чекбоксы:

```
    <script>
                function getChecked() {
            var nodes = $('#tt').tree('getChecked');
            var selected_id = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if (nodes[i].user_id) {
                    selected_id[selected_id.length] = nodes[i].user_id;
                }
            }
            return console.log(selected_id);
        }</script>
```

Как мне передать отмеченные чекбоксы, в контроллер через CActiveForm наряду с другими заполненными полями помимо самих чекбоксов?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

<?php   echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
    'Сохранить',
    '/yii/document/update',
    array(
       'type'=>'POST',
       'data'=> array('selected_id'=>'js:getChecked()',
       'dataType'=>'json',
    ),    array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')
);?>

Всем спасибо, уже разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

На submit повесь функцию, которая выбранные ("зачеканные") значения запишет в hidden поле.